# Blender Material outlines

Tags: export, outliner

How can I add material outlines to the geometry of my model in blender? I want them to be exportable to a game engine as an fbx model. Basically instead of using a shader for outines I want them to be baked into geometry or Textures, is there an easy way of doing that in blender?
Thanks for any help

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures